# Using a destructuring assignment to iterate over an es6 map with nodejs 4.1.2

Tags: node.js

I tried to iterate over an es6 map like described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
for (var [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
```

When running it with nodejs 4.1.2 and the `--harmony` flag I get

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

I could write

```
for (var arr of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(arr[0] + " = " + arr[1]);
}
```

but this is not nice because it is not expressive.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly using the `--harmony_destructuring` flag?

Comment: it works with this flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is made in accordance with [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/5095300).

---

As [@Ben Fortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615209/ben-fortune) has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964681/how-to-iterate-over-an-es6-map-with-nodejs-4-1-2#comment53756610_32964681):

> Have you tried explicitly using the `--harmony_destructuring` flag?

Actual documentation on this flag is hard to find, but more information can be found in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3101) about destructuring assignment in node 4.